# Waiting for incoming connection with ide key:PhpStorm-Xdebug

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I've searched a lot for this problem when debugging php using PhpStorm 2016.1 with `xdebug`, I found 3 or 4 links discussing this problem, but none of them are useful. Here is my configure details screenshots.

[image]

[image]

**Phpstorm Debug setting**
[image]

**DBGp Proxy etting**
[image]

**PHP setting**
[image]

**Debug Profile info**
[image]

**Here is my phpinfo() details**
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Here are my xdebug configuration**

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension ="c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host= "localhost"
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.remote_start = on
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

**Any help highly appreciate, thanks**

Comment: Collect xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session -- https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log -- possibly there are issue with paths mappings. Other than that: With your config all what you may need to click in IDE is "phone handle icon" so that PhpStorm starts listening for incoming debug connections -- you have already configured xdebug to debug every script. P.S. Since you are on localhost -- you don't need `xdebug.remote_connect_back`. I also suggest to enable both "force break..." options from your 3rd screenshot

Comment: @LazyOne I have already enabled the "phone handle icon" that you mentioned. I have done other things you are suggested. now its getting incoming connection. But now getting an another Two errors related to path mapping.

Comment: What kind of errors? You are using XAMPP .. AFAIK it uses symlinks for http root folder .. so if you keep your project files in such path .. you may need to tick `Use path mapping...` option in last screenshot and provide real path mappings there (remember: xdebug works with final/resolved paths while PhpStorm uses the as is). Please provide xdebug log -- it should give some info; as well as details about your project -- what the path you are using to opening it.

Comment: @LazyOne,  Wow, I've been working for hours and this fixed my issue, thanks!

Comment: Please describe what you did exactly and put it as an answer (you can accept your own answers) -- it might be useful for other people who may face similar situation.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. Again, I thanks to you for this suggestions.

Comment: "`Yeah that's a good point`" - so, where is your answer to this highly upvoted question?

Answer (score 1):

I was encounter a similar situation and  worked it out by following steps:
"run" => "Web Server Debug Validation" get some hints and modify my xdebug configuration in php.ini.It's turns out that variable "xdebug.remote_enable" must be  true in my case.